# Android: SetUp API Key for Google Maps

Tags: java, android, xml, maps

I'm trying to get my api key on my development mac pc.
In my terminal I use the following code:

**keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -key
store debug.keystore**

But unfortunately I get the following error back:

device-fdearf:~ mymac$ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -key
Illegal option:  -key
Try keytool -help
device-fdeur6f:~ mymac$ store debug.keystore

How can I fix this?

This what I actually need:
Once you hit the enter key, you'll see something like this (the actual MD5 that we're interested in is the last line):
androiddebugkey, Mar 10, 2009, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): D1:16:4A:BD:73:73:A4:56:9D:CD:9A:44:A2:6C:11:AC

Many Thanks!

Comment: Does this have anything to do with App Engine?

Answer (score 2):

see this [link](http://www.androidpeople.com/tag/fingerprint/).it will provide you step by step simple.

----------what i get error from ur code first glance is you are not giving path of keystore.for more info see above link.